# Creating a window in Qt outside of main()?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qwidget

Is it possible to make a window in Qt outside of the main() function like it's done in the tutorials? What's wrong with they way I did it here? There are no errors when I try to compile, but the window just never shows up. Thanks.

main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "Calculator.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication application(argc, argv);
    Calculator calculator();
    return application.exec();
}
```

Calculator.h

```
class Calculator {
    public:
        Calculator();
};
```

Calculator.cpp

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "Calculator.h"

Calculator::Calculator() {

    QWidget window;
    window.show();

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Curiously, you have two separate errors here :)

1. `window` is a local variable in the constructor that goes out of scope (and thus is destroyed) once the constructor exits. You must use a persistent object (one that lives after the function exits), such as a member of `Calculator`.
2. In `main`, the code `Calculator calculator();` declares a function `calculator` returning `Calculator`. This is a common gotcha when instantiating default-constructed objects in C++. The parentheses are unnecessary (and harmful) in this case.

To fix both errors:

```
class Calculator {
public:
    Calculator();
private:
    QWidget m_window;            // persistent member
};
Calculator::Calculator() {
    m_window.show();
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication application(argc, argv);
    Calculator calculator;       // note, no () after calculator
    return application.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes a lot of sense!